# How to hide the default "not available" web page from Volley

Tags: android, webview, android-volley

I use Volley library to send json request to a REST service. The json result is then parsed and shown in a webView. It works normally except that it shows a "webpage not available" when it is loading. This page disappears after the data is loaded.

I put a progress dialog during loading but it doesn't hide the default webpage completely. Do you have any idea? Thanks!

```
public void search(String input) {
    showProgressDialog(R.string.loading);
    word = RESTTool.encodeForWeb(input);
    String url = "HTTP://restserver.com/" + word;
    Map<String, String> params = RESTTool.getHeader(word); 

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "REST responds successfully");
            hideProgressDialog();
            String html = convertToHtml(response);
            showHtml(html);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            hideProgressDialog();
            Log.d(TAG, "receive error");
            showHtml(HtmlComposer.getHtmlWithContent(getString(R.string.error_no_network)));
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> headers = RESTTool.getHeader(word);
            return headers;
        }

    };
    RESTClient.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks! I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer still shows the "webpage not available" page before the custom error page shows.

My solution is to check if the information has been downloaded from the REST api and show my customized error page at last.

The procedure is like this:

1. Hide the webview before contacting the REST service
2. In my search(String input) function, download the information from the REST api and check if error happens

   ```
   @Override

   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

       hideProgressDialog();
       errorHappened = true;
   }
   ```
3. Override onPageFinished for WebClient and show the customized webpage if error happens. Because the onPageFinished is called all the time, I put two booleans to make sure that the error page is only loaded once. Otherwise, it can cause problem when the fragment is closed.
   I put a button below the webview to close the fragment when error happens. It is not shown when no error happens.

   ```
     WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient() {
       @Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           if(errorHappened && !errorShown){
               webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
               webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               errorShown = true;
               buttonClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           }
       }
       //... other code

      };
      webView.setWebViewClient(client);
      // Show the web page
      webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", webPage, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
      webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you still need an answer.
Just in case, for anyone who would get here, the solution is rather simple.
It should be enough to override the `onReceivedError` method of your `WebViewClient` and provide there an error/loading page to override the default one.

For example if you have custom `customErrorPage.html` page in your asset folder:

```
yourWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/customErrorPage.html");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this function is deprecated now.